# Integral representation of an arbitrary polynomial

Tags: integral-transforms, polynomials

Consider a smooth function $q \colon \mathbb R^2_+ \to \mathbb R_+$ such that $q(\lambda x) = \lambda q(x)$ for any $\lambda > 0$. Denote $x \circ y$ the elementwise product of $x,y \in \mathbb R^2_+$. Let $\Gamma$ be some curve in $\mathbb R^2_+$, transversal to any level curve $[ x \in \mathbb R^2_+ \mid q(x \circ y) = t]$, $y \in \mathbb R^2_+$, $t > 0$ that it intersects. My question is if it is possible to find continuous (or maybe only Lebesgue integrable) functions $f_1(y,t)$ and $f_2(y,t)$ from $ \Gamma \times \mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R_+$ such that
$$
  x_{1}^{n_1}x_2^{n_2} = \int\limits_{\Gamma} f_1(y,q(y \circ x))dy_1+f_2(y,q(y\circ x))dy_2
$$
where $n_1$, $n_2$ are fixed natural numbers. If it isn't possible maybe it is possible to find a sequence $f_1^n$, $f_2^n$ for which such integrals converge to $x_1^{n_1} x_2^{n_2}$ in $\mathbb R^2_+$?